# Evaluation of a logical formula at many values in Z3

Tags: c#, z3

I needed to evaluate the value of an expression over various values of variables using Z3.
I know Z3 is a satisfiabilty checker but model.Eval(Args) causes evaluations of an expression at values of variables generated by model.

So is it possible for us to iterate over various values to evaluate an expression.

Example : p and q at all possible values of  p and q (p,q being Boolean )

So in some sense creating a truth table out of it  using some recursion or iteration.
Is it possible any way for Z3 to do so?

Help with the C# API will be even better.

Thanks

Comment: I have already asked user to enter a logical expression and used Z3 to check if it is a tautology or not by checking the satisfiability of its negation. Now I want the user to see that the expression evaluates always to true ,hence its a tautology and if not a tautology ,then to show the user that it evaluates not always to true and hence it is not a tautology.

Answer (score 1):

You may consider the method `Substitute` in the C# API. It can be used to substitute constants such as `p` and `q` by values. It also simplifies/evaluates the formula after applying the substitution.

Here is a small C# example (from our regression suite) using `Substitute`:

```
using Microsoft.Z3;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Test
{
    public void Run()
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> cfg = new Dictionary<string, string>() { 
            { "AUTO_CONFIG", "true" } };

        using (Context ctx = new Context(cfg))
        {
            IntExpr x = ctx.MkIntConst("x");
            IntExpr y = ctx.MkIntConst("y");

            FuncDecl f = ctx.MkFuncDecl("f", new Sort[] { ctx.IntSort, ctx.IntSort }, ctx.IntSort);
            FuncDecl g = ctx.MkFuncDecl("g", new Sort[] { ctx.IntSort }, ctx.IntSort);
            Expr n = f[f[g[x], g[g[x]]], g[g[y]]];

            Console.WriteLine(n);

            Expr nn = n.Substitute(new Expr[] { g[g[x]], g[y] }, 
                                   new Expr[] { y, ctx.MkAdd(x, ctx.MkInt(1)) } );

            Console.WriteLine(nn);

            Console.WriteLine(n.Substitute(g[g[x]], y));
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, you will have to write a loop to iterate over all possible values.
In Python, you can use list comprehensions: http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/56
Another option is to use the method `Simplify`. This method can be used to evaluate formulas that do not contains uninterpreted symbols such as `p` and `q`.
Here is another example in Python: http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/PC
I'm using Python because we don't have support for running C# examples in the browser.
Note that, the Z3 API in C# contains all the functionality of the Python one.

Finally, another possibility is to enumerate models.
By doing it, you are essentially producing all values of `p` and `q` that satisfy the formula (i.e., make it true). The idea is to add new constraints that block the current model, and solve again. Here is a small script in Python for doing it:
http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/PDJ

The constraint `block` is used to block the current model. If we uncomment `print block`, we can also print it for each model produced by Z3. Of course, this approach does not terminate if there are infinite models that satisfy the formula like in this example:
http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/X0l

These examples can be encoded in C#. Here is a C# example demonstrating how to iterate over the constants (and functions) in a model, and obtaining their interpretation:

```
using Microsoft.Z3;
using System;

class Test
{

    public void Run()
    {        
        using (Context ctx = new Context())
        {
            Sort U = ctx.MkUninterpretedSort("U");
            FuncDecl f = ctx.MkFuncDecl("f", U, U);
            Expr a = ctx.MkConst("a", U);
            Expr b = ctx.MkConst("b", U);
            Expr c = ctx.MkConst("c", U);

            Solver s = ctx.MkSolver();
            s.Assert(ctx.MkEq(f[f[a]], b),
                     ctx.MkNot(ctx.MkEq(f[b], c)),
                     ctx.MkEq(f[c], c));
            Console.WriteLine(s.Check());
            Model m = s.Model;
            foreach (FuncDecl d in m.Decls)
                if (d.DomainSize == 0)
                    Console.WriteLine(d.Name + " -> " + m.ConstInterp(d));
                else 
                    Console.WriteLine(d.Name + " -> " + m.FuncInterp(d));

            Console.WriteLine(m.NumSorts);
            Console.WriteLine(m.Sorts[0]);

            foreach(Sort srt in m.Sorts)
                Console.WriteLine(srt);

            foreach (Expr v in m.SortUniverse(U))
                Console.WriteLine(v);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry! This may seem silly to you but I am getting an error "Error 1 'Microsoft.Z3.Context' does not contain a definition for 'MkUninterpretedSort' and no extension method 'MkUninterpretedSort' accepting a first argument of type 'Microsoft.Z3.Context' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\Pulkit\Documents\Visual Studio 11\Projects\ConsoleApplication4\ConsoleApplication4\Program.cs 11 26 ConsoleApplication4
"
and similar errors. I have already made a reference of all Dll's and pasted them in the bin and bin/Debug directory.
Please direct me ahead.

Comment: These examples are for Z3 4.0, and they are based on the new .NET API. Which version are you using? Here is the documentation of the new API: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/z3/class_microsoft_1_1_z3_1_1_context.html

Comment: I tried adding reference to from z3-3.2 and z3-4.0 both. None worked!!
Still thanks for so much help>

Comment: Can you compile the C# example that comes with Z3 4.0? Did you try to use the Visual Studio command prompt? To compile the file `tst.cs` that uses Z3, I use the following command line: `csc /reference:[Z3_PATH]\bin\microsoft.z3.dll /out:tst.exe tst.cs`

Comment: No it does not compile in the command prompt too and gives same errors!!I did include Microsoft.z3.dll as reference

Comment: Could you send me the following information? .cs source files, exact command line you used, Visual studio version, location where Z3 is installed. You can send it to my private email, or add a link here to a shared directory such as dropbox. Thanks.

Comment: If you are using the 32 bit DLL in a 64 bit machine, you must also include the option `/platform:x86`. Thanks to Nikolaj for pointing that out.

Comment: Thanks! The process mentioned in the mail worked out for me. I also had to include the folder containing the Microsoft.Z3.dll in Properties->Reference for the project. Thanks Nikolaj And Leonardo.