# Z3_test_1.exe[2448] unhandled exception in Microsoft .net framework

Tags: z3

I wrote the following program in visual studio 2010(Version: 10.0.30319.1 RTMREL) with C# language and the version of .net framework is 4.0.30319 RTMREL. There is no errors or warnings when compiling, but it throw an exception when running the program. The exception is that "Z3_test_1.exe[2448] unhandled exception happened in Microsoft .net framework", Where Z3_test_1.exe is the program file name. The Z3 prover I used is in version Z3 4.0 and in the program i used Microsoft.Z3.dll rather than Microsoft.Z3V3.dll.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Z3;
//using Microsoft.Z3V3;

namespace Z3_test_1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
                using (Context ctx = new Context())
                {
                    RealExpr c = ctx.MkRealConst("c");
                    BoolExpr Eqzero = ctx.MkGt(c,ctx.MkReal(0));    
                    BoolExpr Gezero = ctx.MkGe(c,ctx.MkReal(0));
                    BoolExpr Lttwo = ctx.MkLt(c,ctx.MkReal(2));
                    BoolExpr Gtthree = ctx.MkGt(c,ctx.MkReal(3)); 
                    BoolExpr b1 = ctx.MkBoolConst("b1");
                    BoolExpr b2 = ctx.MkBoolConst("b2");
                    BoolExpr b3 = ctx.MkBoolConst("b3");
                    BoolExpr b0 = ctx.MkBoolConst("b0");   

                    RealExpr[] lamb=new RealExpr[1];
                    lamb[0]=ctx.MkRealConst("lamb");
                    BoolExpr  temp=ctx.MkAnd(ctx.MkGt(lamb[0],ctx.MkReal(0)),ctx.MkEq(b0,ctx.MkTrue()),ctx.MkEq(b1,ctx.MkTrue()),ctx.MkGe(ctx.MkAdd(c,lamb[0]),ctx.MkReal(0)),ctx.MkLe(ctx.MkAdd(c,lamb[0]),ctx.MkReal(3)),ctx.MkGe(c,ctx.MkReal(0)),ctx.MkLe(c,ctx.MkReal(3)));   
                    BoolExpr exist = ctx.MkExists(lamb, temp, 1, null, null, ctx.MkSymbol("Q2"),ctx.MkSymbol("skid2"));
                    Console.WriteLine(exist.ToString());
                    Solver s1 = ctx.MkSolver();
                    s1.Assert(exist);
                    if (s1.Check() == Status.SATISFIABLE){
                        Console.WriteLine("get pre");
                        Console.Write(s1);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Not reach");
                    }
                    Console.ReadKey();
                }   

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you run the program in debug mode or standalone? Where is `Microsoft.Z3.dll`? It is a good idea to set `CopyLocal = True` in Visual Studio so necessary dlls are in the same folder with the executable file?

Comment: (1)I run the program by ctrl+F5 in vs2010( or with the menu of vs2010:  Debug--run without debug);   (2) Microsoft.z3.dll isn't in the same directory with the program. In fact ,Microsoft.z3.dll is in disk F; while the program is in disk D. (3)For the refernce of Microsoft.z3.dll, CopyLocal =True is alreay set.

Comment: (4)When I run the program in standalone, the same exception happened again.

Comment: (5)As i checked just now, Microsoft.z3.dll is in the same directory with the executable program file because CopyLocal=true.

Comment: (A) Make sure that `z3.dll` (important) and `Microsoft.Z3.dll` are in Debug folder? (B) Compile the project to x86 or x64 based on which Z3 dlls you're referencing.

Comment: (1)After I copied Micrsofot.z3.dll to Debug folder ,there is still an exception even though the exception code changed. And after I copied all the files from "Z3.Microsoft Research\Z3-4.0\bin" to the Debug folder, there is still an  unhandled exception happened in Microsoft .net framework. The exception code is [3020] sometimes,2272 sometime else.(2)I complile the project to x86

Comment: Did you check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10663994/evaluation-of-a-logical-formula-at-many-values-in-z3? The comments section discuss a similar compilation problem.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce your errors. The test works just fine for me.
I suspect it is the same compilation problem that Leo points out because it worked for me. The subtle problem is that if you reference an x86 assembly from a x64 environment, or the other round, then runtime errors start happening. The fool-proof way is to add a /platform indication with the arguments you pass to the compiler (csc.exe).