# An error appears when running Z3 in C#

Tags: c#, z3

Can anyone please help!
When I tried to run the code below, I got this error:

> " Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Z3, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9c8d792caae602a2' or one of its
>   dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect
>   format "

Here is the code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)

    {

        using (Context ctx = new Context())
        {

            RealExpr c = ctx.MkRealConst("c");

            BoolExpr Eqzero = ctx.MkGt(c, ctx.MkReal(0));
            BoolExpr Gezero = ctx.MkGe(c, ctx.MkReal(0));
            BoolExpr Lttwo = ctx.MkLt(c, ctx.MkReal(2));
            BoolExpr Gtthree = ctx.MkGt(c, ctx.MkReal(3));
            BoolExpr b1 = ctx.MkBoolConst("b1");
            BoolExpr b2 = ctx.MkBoolConst("b2");
            BoolExpr b3 = ctx.MkBoolConst("b3");
            BoolExpr b0 = ctx.MkBoolConst("b0");
            RealExpr[] lamb = new RealExpr[1];
            lamb[0] = ctx.MkRealConst("lamb");
            BoolExpr temp = ctx.MkAnd(ctx.MkGt(lamb[0], ctx.MkReal(0)), ctx.MkEq(b0, ctx.MkTrue()), ctx.MkEq(b1, ctx.MkTrue()), ctx.MkGe(ctx.MkAdd(c, lamb[0]), ctx.MkReal(0)), ctx.MkLe(ctx.MkAdd(c, lamb[0]), ctx.MkReal(3)), ctx.MkGe(c, ctx.MkReal(0)), ctx.MkLe(c, ctx.MkReal(3)));
            BoolExpr exist = ctx.MkExists(lamb, temp, 1, null, null, ctx.MkSymbol("Q2"), ctx.MkSymbol("skid2"));
            Console.WriteLine(exist.ToString());
            Solver s1 = ctx.MkSolver();
            s1.Assert(exist);
            if (s1.Check() == Status.SATISFIABLE)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("get pre");
                Console.Write(s1);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Not reach");
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

    }
}
```

}

Comment: I think you're referencing 32-bit `Microsoft.Z3.dll` in a 64-bit machine or vice versa. Make sure you reference the right Z3 version and check the compilation procedure in comments to this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10663994/evaluation-of-a-logical-formula-at-many-values-in-z3

Comment: thank you but I refereced 64-bit Microsoft.Z3.dll in a 64-bit machine

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use `build.cmd` script in `examples/dotnet` folder and modify it according to your need. The script copies `Microsoft.Z3.dll` and `z3.dll` to the working directory and compiles the code on the corresponding platform.

If you compile from Visual Studio:

- Make sure that `Microsoft.Z3.dll`'s version you reference matches with the platform (x86, x64,...) which you're compiling to. There are two Z3 versions in `bin` and `x64` folder.
- Include the folder containing the `Microsoft.Z3.dll` in *Project Properties*->*Reference Paths*. The reason is that `Microsoft.Z3.dll` uses unmanaged `z3.dll`, which you cannot directly reference in Visual Studio.

Comment: i followed all the instructions but really did not work !!! is there another suggestion please ?

Comment: What is your `Platform` option (x86, x64, AnyCPU) in Visual Studio? How did you run the code?

Comment: i am using (x86)in Visual Studio, and I copied all .dlls and Microsoft.Z3.dll's which are under x86 folder and paste them in the same path with c# code

Comment: If you run the program inside Visual Studio, it should be fine. If you run the program outside VS, you should copy `z3.dll` and `Microsoft.Z3.dll` to the same folder as the executable file.

Comment: Actually i run it inside Visual Studio, thats why I see that is strange

Answer (score 1):

In the comments to the previous answers to this question, reference to the x86 distribution and to the x64 distribution were made, and I am not sure this issue is resolved. To clarify:

When compiling a 64-bit binary (called x64 in visual studio), then the 64-bit versions of z3.dll and Microsoft.Z3.dll are required. Those are found in the folder called **x64** in the Z3 distribution. Note that this does **not** depend on the actual machine that Visual Studio is running on.

When compiling a 32-bit binary, then the dlls from the **bin** directory are required. Again, this does **not** depend on the actual machine that Visual Studio is running on.

Visual Studio can cross-compile from 32 to 64 bit and vice versa, i.e., it is possible to compile a binary for the 32-bit architecture (called **x86** as opposed to **x64**) on 64-bit machines. It is also possible to compile 64-bit binaries on a 32-bit machine. Depending on what kind of binary is being compiled, the right set of dlls must be added. The setting that matters is in the build configuration of your project in Visual Studio (on top, usually next to the where debug/release mode is selected). At this compilation stage, it does not matter what type of machine the compilation is being performed on. The actual machine only matters when an attempt is made to run a 64-bit binary on a 32-bit machine (but then the error message will be different from the one reported). Running 32-bit binaries on 64-bit machines usually works fine (but the maximum memory usage of the program will be limited).

I hope this helped to remove some of the confusion!

Also, we agree that the combined distribution including both versions creates some unnecessary confusion, so in the future we will consider distributing separate installers for the 32-bit and the 64-bit binaries.