# BadImageFormatException when using Z3 C# API

Tags: c#, z3

I meet an exception says"BadImageFormatException unhandled" when I use Z3 C# API. In fact I have added the reference of  "Microsoft.Z3.dll" and I use .NET framework 4.0. The detailed the information is

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Z3, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9c8d792caae602a2' or one of its
>   dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect
>   format.

So what's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the answers to this question:
[An error appears when running Z3 in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11136324/an-error-appears-when-running-z3-in-c-sharp)

It's probably related to the Platform target you've selected in your project properties: x86, x64 or AnyCPU. Reference the 32-bit or 64-bit version of Microsoft.Z3 as appropriate.

Lots of other suggestions at the above link too.